# How to watch multiple property change using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, properties, watch

I have two properties to watch for and update the third depends on change in first two.
here is my code
Can anyone help me on this?

```
return {
        context: 'prop1',
        watch: [
                {
                   property: ["prop2","prop3"], // this to watch for
                   update: [
                   {
                       dest: "prop4", // update this prop based on change in prop2 and prop3
                       src: [function (value) {
                           if (value.prop2change === 'thisvalue') { 
                               return prop3changevalue;
                           }
                           else
                               return 0;
                       },"newValue"]
                   }
             }
         ]
     }
```

Comment: Might be a use case for [$watchCollection](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)? (scroll down a bit to the documentation on it)

Comment: I change my code like this and it works but still i have some issues. src:["prop2","prop3",function(prop2value, prop3value){ do same...} ] i get my prop updated but i have a question - Can I have multiple destinations as well?                                                                    something like this is possile ?  ------                        if (prop2changevalue = 'thisvalue' ) then update prop4 else update prop5

Answer (score 0):

Using [$scope.$watchGroup](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watchGroup), which is new in angular.js 1.3 ( In angular 1.2 use $watch )

```
   $scope.igor = 'Ershov'
   $scope.matias = 'Pachuli'

   var names = ['igor', 'matias']

   $scope.$watchGroup(names, function(newValues, oldValues) {
        // do something


      });
```

newValues and oldValues are arrays and indecies correspond to index of property in first parameter to $watchGroup.

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7je6r2mn/1/

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me on Angular 1.6. If I put a console log on the function, I can see that it just runs once with newValues and oldValues as undefined, while individually watching the properties work as usual.

Comment: @AlejandroIglesias what are your `igor` and `matias` ? objects or primitives?

Comment: One is an object and the other two are primitives.

Comment: @AlejandroIglesias  And primitives doesn't work too? I would think that watchGroup doesnt check properties of the object to be changes, only reference to the object to stay the same. but primitieves have to work.

Comment: @AlejandroIglesias Also it has to be on `$scope`. ie wouldn't work with ControllerAs syntax

Comment: @AlejandroIglesias added link to jsfiddle with example

Comment: Thanks. The watch doesn't run for any of the properties. One question is: does it work for bindings passed to the directive? I'm also using `controllerAs`.
So DDO would be: `{scope: {myProp: '<'}, bindToController: true, controllerAs: '$ctrl', ...` (showing only one of the bindings, but as mentioned, there are many).